# Why code in stack or heap segment can be executed?

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow

In the security field, there are heap exploitation and stack smashing attack.

But I found that `/proc/*/maps` file, the heap and stack segment, 
only have `rw-p`-permission.

There is no execution permission in the these two segments. 
My engineer friends told me that if you have `rw` permission in the Intel CPU, your code will got the execution permission automatically.
But I can not understand why Intel do this design?

Comment: That used to be true, but Intel processors have had the [NX-bit option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit) for the past decade.

Comment: @HansPassant But only in long mode (64-bit page table entries).

Comment: You might have to  take a look of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection Actually, code in stack or heap segment can't be executed even you jump to that. You will got segmentation fault. That's because your segment (stack or heap) doesn't have execution permission, but you try to execute it. Then cpu throw out the exception.

Answer (score 2):

That is because all segments in Linux (Windows also) have the same base address and the same size. Code is always accessed via code segment and code segment covers exactly the same area as stack (or any other) segment, so you can execute code wherever it is.

**EDIT:**

you can read more here: http://www.intel.com/Assets/en_US/PDF/manual/253668.pdf
Chapter 3.2 USING SEGMENTS

Comment: This is not correct. 
Except you compile your code with parameter `-z execstack`, otherwise program is NX protected.

Comment: Here is a simple tool to check your segment is NX protected.http://www.trapkit.de/tools/checksec.html

Comment: @bananaappletw: 32 bit mode does not support NXE protection (which is mentioned in document I've given). But yes, in 64 bit (IA-32e) mode it is possible to use it but only at paging level (not segment level).

Comment: I have no idea what you talk about. Your latter reply is correct. But your answer is wrong. Like this line: `you can execute code wherever it is`. If it acted like you said, then what's NX protection for.

Comment: @bananaappletw: I've used `you can execute code wherever it is` expression in terms of segments. NX protection is not part of segmentation protection and is not available for every x86 cpu.

Comment: I still have no idea what you talk about. The content of question is wrong, the author's engineer friend is wrong. You didn't point this out. Instead, try to use ambiguous operating concept to answer the question. However,  you try to conduct this argument to another unrelated direction now. I don't even talk about  how CPU works with operating system.

Comment: @bananaappletw: write your own answer then.